# Populate a jcombobox in netbeans 7.1

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, netbeans

I want to add a combo box which populates from a mysql database in netbeans 7.1.I did a simple implementation like follows, but this coding doesn't work.

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try 
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/combo","root","root123");
        Statement stmnt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM items";
        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(SQL);
        while(rs.next()) 
        {
            jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("itemcode"));
        }
    } 
    ...
}
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Please describe the expected and actual result.

Comment: I want to see item codes in the dropdown menu like:

Itemcode1
Itemcode2
Itemcode3
...etc

Comment: Is there any result from running this code? If not, try adding the catch block at the bottom of the try block and see what happens.

Comment: This doesn't give any result. The code has a catch block. I didn't post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your combobox consists of String items. You are to create a combobox which will use these string items in its display.

```
String items[] = {...};
```

Sample combobox declaration could be like this:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items);
```

So populating the `items` array via the data coming from your database could be a solution to your problem, i.e. combobox has nothing to do with database, but string items have.

```
int index = 0;
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
while(rs.next())
   items[index] = rs.getString("itemcode");
```

However, since you don't know how many items you will retrieve from the database you can use an arraylist instead of an array so that you can dynamically add items to the list.

Comment: thanks for killing your time on my question.
I tried to do this but problems doesn't solve. I want to know that adding codes to  this method "private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)" is correct ?? I think problem is this. because when I'm running the program the drop down menu shows the default values stetted by netbeans(Item1,Item2....) I'm new to programming so I don't know how to get rid of this

Comment: @Grant you want to have a combobox which will show items from database. will it refresh itself? no. so firstly populate your items from database then set this array to your combobox. combobox is just a gui component, it has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: Yes I got the point. My program fetches values from database correctly & stores in an array, but the problem is when I'm going to show values in combo box list using jComboBox1.addItems(); statement it does not show any value returned from the database.

Comment: @Grant don't use jComboBox1.addItems(); when you declare your combobox just use this JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items); where items is the array populated via database.

Comment: When I'm double clicking the combo box in j frame form net beans points me to this method "private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)" Where I need to add this piece of code "JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items);" please explain me. I'm just a beginner in gui. :)

Comment: jComboBox1ActionPerformed is a method that you put some code that will execute when a particular item. when you define your combobox variable, i mean the very beginning of your code use this JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items); but of course this statement should come after you populated "items". ok?

Comment: if it works for you, upvote and put a tick on my answer to appreciate my effort. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try {

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///dbname", "username", "password");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    Resultset r=st.executeQuary("SELECT * FROM table name");
     while(r.next()){
        Vector v=new Vector();
        ComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(v));
     }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please leave 4 spaces before the start of the 'try' block to accommodate that in the coding paragraph.